# How can I partially hide asp.net checkboxlist items

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am writing an asp.net page with faceted navigation. I've got a bunch of filters which are rendered as checkboxlists. These checkboxlists can get very long (e.g. countries and regions). On page load, I would like to show just 8 options for each category with a More button underneath. If the user clicks on More, then just that category's option list should expand. I tried doing this with

```
chkBoxCountryNameList.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle["display"] = "none";
```

This works, but when ASP.NET renders the CheckBoxList, it does so using a table, with each CheckBox control nested within its own  element. This means that even though the items I don't want to see aren't displayed, the white space for their rows is, so there's quite a bit of whites pace I still need to content with.

I thought of another way, which is to go server side and fetch the rest of the items, but that is very server side heavy.

What's the best option to do this client side, so that I don't have to go server side and re-query the database?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to hide also the table row for each checkboxes you want to hide. search on how to run javascript on code-behind then run this javascript code everytime you render the checkboxlist.

```
function hideCheckBoxes() {
    $("table[id$='idOfCheckboxList']").find(":checkbox:hidden").each(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    });
}
```

edit:
you can use :gt jquery selector to satisfy your needs
http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

```
function hideCheckBoxes() {
    $("table[id$='idOfCheckboxList']").find(":checkbox:gt(8)").each(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I suppose the code you showed me would rely on me going server side to hide the checkboxes first, and then kick javascript in to hide the <tr> tags. I would like to do everything client side. Is there a way of hiding all <tr>s except the first 8? That way I cut out a server trip.